# MongoDB Ascending/Descending Targeting Wrong Value

Tags: python, mongodb, discord, discord.py

When trying to get my code to put total_points in order of highest to lowest, I noticed that it's sorting the IDs instead.

```py
        lb_data = main_db['challenges'].find().sort("total_points", pymongo.DESCENDING)
        embed = discord.Embed(title='**Challenge Leaderboard**',
                            description='''description msg''', color=discord.Colour.red())
        for i, x in enumerate(lb_data, 1):
            if 'total_points' in x:
                total_points = str(x['total_points'])
            else:
                total_points = "0"
            embed.add_field(name=f"#{i}", value=f"<@{str(x['id'])}> has {total_points}", inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I am not sure how to get it to target total_points as I believe I've already specified it right after .sort

Comment: can you put a sample of the data in the MongoDB?

Comment: https://file.coffee/u/g9gsTgOxyc.png

Comment: I did a dummy database and replicated this, but to me it works fine. Here is what I did for each part: json file (https://file.coffee/u/QO0QeDQuOr.jpeg) How it looks on the mongodb (https://file.coffee/u/wREnMlK2EA.jpeg), the code I try it with (https://file.coffee/u/fr5x7GahRv.jpeg) bot working (https://file.coffee/u/eyAxwikXP-.jpeg). I don't know why is not working on your end.

Comment: Well, you used the same IDs on your end. When I use the command, it orders the IDs from highest to lowest, not the total points. That may be the reason for why you're getting a different result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this changing your first line with this:

```
lb_data = main_db['challenges'].find()._addSpecial( "$orderby", { total_points : -1 } )
```

Comment: That throws this error: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute '_addSpecial'